# How to get nonce for password hashing for post request?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, network-programming, http-post, nonce

I'm trying to gather information from a router (model BGW-210) with BS4 and Python for automation. The Wi-Fi information page requires a device access code which I have available. However, the access code is hashed with a nonce using md5 in the format of: md5('access code' + 'nonce'). The post form looks like this:

```
payload = {
   'nonce': '',
   'password': 'access code',
   'hashpassword': '',
   'Continue': 'Continue'
}
```

The router also changes each of the letter of the **password** into '*' for each letter in the field after hashing when I inspected the Payload in the Network tab from my browser.

Here's what I have so far

```
    s = requests.Session()
    res = s.get(bgw_210['login_url'], headers=headers)
    cookies = dict(res.cookies)

    headers['Content-Type']= 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    res = s.post(bgw_210['login_url'], headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
    html = res.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

    # I can get the nonce value from here
    print(soup.find('input', {"name":"nonce"}).attrs['value'])
    payload = {
            'nonce': '',
            'password': 'access code',
            #'password': '**********',
            'hashpassword': '',
            'Continue': 'Continue',
            }
```

The nonce would change if I update the payload with the hash password and would no longer be valid. I've tried post requesting with fixed values from the payload that I monitored and input manually via the browser.